# How to combine two excel-sheets with similar information for different years using MS access?

Tags: r, excel, ms-access

Okay! So I have two data sets containing similar information but one covers year 2001 to 2012, and the other 2013 to 2016. Both begin with a column with a defining ID-number, followed by one separate column for each year containing a value for each specific ID-number. I cant figure out a way to simply add the newer columns to the old sheet, so that I have a sheet containing information for year 2001-2016. I think the issue might be that the different time-series does not contain perfectly matching ID-numbers. Example, there is ID a b c d in 2001-2012 but in 2013-2016 there is only ID a c d.

Does anyone have a way for me to do this? Would be greatly appreciated! I can use both MS excel and MS access, or R if there is a way to do it there.

Comment: So far I have tried using access and the information from here: [link](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/using-access-to-combine-multiple-excel-files-method-1/comment-page-2/). That did not work, and i got the following error-message: The number of columns in the selected tables or queries of a union query do not match.

Comment: Can you share a little bit of the data you are working with? It's tough to provide guidance without knowing what you are working with. Also please provide your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your union query will work if you use queries with equal count of fields.

So for the 2013-2016 data, use something like:

```
Select a, b, c, Null as d
From yourtable
```